# A few questions on tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

1. What is the difference between my tf.data.Dataset.batch() value and model.fit(batch_size=x)? Do they need to be the same?
2. I think my dataset can fit into RAM. Do I just use tf.data.Dataset.cache() and I'm done? Is prefetch and batch or AUTOTUNE even necessary if everything is already loaded into RAM?
3. What is the benefit of tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()? Should I use this if my dataset is already in an initially random order?

Comment: I feel like this question isn't quite ready for SO. This is pretty much questions about the API  which could be answered by trying them out. For example, can you make an example with your Dataset and a model.fit? According to the doc's, https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/ , " Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, ..."

Comment: The other two questions seem to be answered in the docs. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache so it sounds like you should still use prefetch and cache will keep it in memory for subsequent iterations. Maybe you can narrow your question down a bit, and include specific usage?